# Using a 1G Ethernet Pass-Thru with BL460C G7 blade?

Tags: networking, hp, blade-server, blade-chassis

I've installed a new G7 BL460C into my HP BladeSystem C7000 enclosure.  I have not had a G7 before.  In the enclosure I have two 1GB Ethernet Pass-Thru interconnect modules (406740-B21).  I am able to assign ports on the pass-thru modules to the G7 blade.  However, when I connect network cables to the ports, I get no link or activity lights.  In the OS on the blade, the network cards are also unable to communicate with the network.

I know the G7's got the new FlexFabric NICs.  I have been searching all day for documentation on whether these are compatible with the 1G pass-thru module to no avail.

Here are my current firmware versions:
On-board administrator: 4.5
Ethernet pass-thrus: 2.8.3
Blade ROM: I27
Blade iLO: 1.61

I'm wondering if the 1G pass-thrus can be used with the G7's after a firmware update (I saw that 3.0.3 is available).  If so, how do I go about doing the update?  I can't find anywhere in the UI to update the switch's firmware.

If not, what is the part number of the new ethernet switch I should be using with a G7+ blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it took me another week, but I think I can answer all of my questions.

I was able to update the firmware of the switches by connecting to the enclosure with SSH.  Then run the command 'UPDATE DEVICE ICBAY [ALL | BayNumber]'.

Even after a firmware update, the switches would not operate with the G7 Servers.

I purchased a pair of HP 1/10Gb VC-Enet Modules (part number 399593-B22) and they work perfectly with the G7 servers.